# Sidebar Navbar twitter bootstrap toggled only on xs screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar, sidebar, screen-size

Is there a way to hide sidebar navbar only on xs screens with a button to show it.
I think the world is "toggled" (not sure about the translate...)

I would like to do it in twitter bootstrap class (not in css if possible)
Actually I have :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-lg shadow-lg align-items-start sidebar sidebar-dark accordion p-0" style="background-color: rgb(255,69,57);">
```

I can't find how to do it like expand : navbar-expand-lg
I tried : navbar-toggled-xs but didn't work.

Comment: If i add toggled to the class then it’s toggled on every screens not only xs...